# Counting logins per device per user

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a query (and don't have much experience) which almost does what I want.

I have a table that contains logins per user per device (table 1) and a table with a set of users I want the results for (table 2). I want to count how many times user x from table 2 has logged on to a device in table 1.

```
Table 1 (data):
username
device_id
logon_date

Table 2 (users): 
username
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT data.device_id
     , COUNT(data.username)
     , data.username 
  FROM data
     , users 
 WHERE data.username = users.username 
 GROUP 
    BY data.device_id
```

But this only lists each device once. I know some users have logged on to the same device. So I would expect the device to be mentioned more than once.

```
device user login count
PC1 - user1 - 12
PC2 - user2 - 20
etc
```

If I would write out my query it would be like this: For every user in table 2 count every login in table 1 and count logins per device.

So it should look like:

```
device user login count
PC1 - user1 - 12
PC1 - user2 - 60
PC2 - user1 - 5
PC2 - user2 - 20
PC2 - user3 - 14
etc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your table structure and example data

Comment: Can we see what your table look like and give us an example of the output you'd like to have please?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "I would expect the device to be mentioned more than once.". A "group by" on the device_id field specifically makes it so that the rows for each device are _grouped_ into a single row, and then you're counting up how many times that device appears in the raw data. I think perhaps you want to group by device_id _and_ username.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Did not know that was possible. Good for some extra reading!

Comment: No problem. I have written it as the answer, so you can mark it "accepted" for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0):

> "I would expect the device to be mentioned more than once.".

A "group by" on the device_id field specifically makes it so that the rows for each device are grouped into a single row, and then you're counting up how many times that device appears in the raw data.

I think perhaps you want to group by both the device_id and the username, e.g.:

```
SELECT data.device_id
     , data.username 
     , COUNT(data.username)
  FROM data
     , users 
 WHERE data.username = users.username 
 GROUP 
    BY data.device_id, data.username
```